# Incorrigible error keeps popping ug, can't solve, help please?

Tags: java

I'm a newbie to Java and I keep getting this stupid error that I can't solve. Here's my code:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
       System.out.print1n("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

This is the error I keep getting while I try compiling:

```
error: Cannot find symbol
symbol: method print1n (String)
location: variable out of type PrintStream
```

Naargh...

Answer (score 3):

You've type the method incorrectly. Here's the corrected line:

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

That's `println`, with and "L", not a "1." That's because `println` stands for PrintLine, hence the spelling.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the 1 with an l, it's printLn (as in "print line"), not "print one n".